# MYSQL - Capitalize the first letter of the first word in each sentence

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column in a mysql table that users have added data.  Some users like to use proper capitalization, some like uppercase words, some all lower case.

**What I want to do is change:**
CHECK BUILDING.

**To:**
Check building.

**And:**
DELIVER PAPERS. UNLOCK DOORS.

**To:**
Deliver papers. Unlock doors.

I assume a function could do this so I can re-use it.

Any ideas?

I tried this but it does each word not the first word in a sentence.

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE c CHAR(1);
    DECLARE s VARCHAR(128);
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE bool INT DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE punct CHAR(17) DEFAULT '?.!-';
    SET s = LCASE( str );
    WHILE i < LENGTH( str ) DO
        BEGIN
            SET c = SUBSTRING( s, i, 1 );
            IF LOCATE( c, punct ) > 0 THEN
                SET bool = 1;
            ELSEIF bool=1 THEN
                BEGIN
                    IF c >= 'a' AND c <= 'z' THEN
                        BEGIN
                            SET s = CONCAT(LEFT(s,i-1),UCASE(c),SUBSTRING(s,i+1));
                            SET bool = 0;
                        END;
                    ELSEIF c >= '0' AND c <= '9' THEN
                        SET bool = 0;
                    END IF;
                END;
            END IF;

            SET i = i+1;
        END;
    END WHILE;
    RETURN s;
END
```

Comment: Well you could try to make some attempts yourself - if it doesn't work - show what you have tried & maybe you will get some suggestions on how to make it work.

Comment: Edited with what i tried. Not to keen on mysql functions.  Figured this has to be an issue someone has came across before so why reinvent the wheel if some person has a function to share that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use triggers to make sure data is stored the way you decide!

Comment: Would still need a function to format the data. That is the part I am really struggling with.

`DECLARE punct CHAR(17) DEFAULT ' ()[]{},.-_!@;:?/';`

I Changed to 

`DECLARE punct CHAR(17) DEFAULT '?.!-';`

Still not working as I expected it.

Comment: As the code you copied was specifically to change the first character of every word to uppercase, have you made any attempts (other than limiting the punct string) to make this do what you want it to?

Comment: I am not sure how to get it to work. All my attempts have not worked as I would have liked.  Maybe I am barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 0):

There's no MySQL function to do that. This function capitalize the first letter of every word in a string.

```
CREATE FUNCTION CAP_FIRST (input VARCHAR(255))

RETURNS VARCHAR(255)

DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN
    DECLARE len INT;
    DECLARE i INT;

    SET len   = CHAR_LENGTH(input);
    SET input = LOWER(input);
    SET i = 0;

    WHILE (i < len) DO
        IF (MID(input,i,1) = ' ' OR i = 0) THEN
            IF (i < len) THEN
                SET input = CONCAT(
                    LEFT(input,i),
                    UPPER(MID(input,i + 1,1)),
                    RIGHT(input,len - i - 1)
                );
            END IF;
        END IF;
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN input;
END;
```

References [link](http://joezack.com/2008/10/20/mysql-capitalize-function/).

Comment: Only problem being it capitalizes each word, not just the first word of each sentence.